# How to print value in a TextInput when a Button is pressed? (Kivi)

Tags: python-3.x, class, kivy

I'm making a logging GUI but I can't find how to print the values of two TextInputs when a button is pressed.

**This is my `.py`:**

```
import kivy

from kivy.app               import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout     import BoxLayout

#[...]  

class Login_Screen(BoxLayout):
    def register(self):
        print('Hi! I want here have the user and password, so later I can make a proper register function.')
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Login_Screen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

**This is my `.kv`:** (The important part is in the last line.)

```
#[...]

<Login_Screen>:
    #[...]

    BoxLayout:
        AnchorLayout:
            #[...]
            TextInput01: # Come from @TextInput
                id: user_input              

    BoxLayout:
        #[...]
        AnchorLayout:
            TextInput01: # Come from @TextInput
                id: password_input

    BoxLayout:
        Button01: # Come from @Button
            id: login
            text: 'Login'
        Button01: # Come from @Button
            id: register
            text: 'Register'
            on_press: root.register()
```

`#[...]` is code that I delete in order to make this more clear.

I want to print `password_input` value and `user_input` value  when I press `register`.
The code must be in the `.py` file because I don't want exactly only print the values, I want to make something more functional but this in an example for me to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the snippet and example below.

## Snippet

```
def register(self):
    print("user: ", self.ids.user_input.text)
    print("password: ", self.ids.password_input.text)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Login_Screen(BoxLayout):

    def register(self):
        print("user: ", self.ids.user_input.text)
        print("password: ", self.ids.password_input.text)


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Login_Screen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Login_Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        AnchorLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: user_input

    BoxLayout:
        AnchorLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: password_input

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: login
            text: 'Login'
        Button:
            id: register
            text: 'Register'
            on_press: root.register()
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I want to make you a question if you don't mind (you aren't obligate to answer): Is possible modify the `register()` to be able to be inside the `MainApp` instead of the `Login_Screen` class and keep working?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. (1) You have to move the register() method into the MainApp() class. (2) In the register() method, add "root" into the print() method e.g. self.root.ids.user_input.text, and self.root.ids.password_input.text. (3) In the kv file, replace "on_press: root.register()" with "on_press: app.register()"